# Code Push Cordova plugin PushNotification not found

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, push-notification, phonegap

I have an issue with Cordova push plugin on android. First let me say it works fine on IOS. On Android however, when I try to call PushNotification from my javascript, the PushNotification object does not exist. It's as if the plugin would not be installed. But it is.

Any direction on what to check would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Here is my build:

> Android Studio project detected cordova-android-support-gradle-release
>   ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION:  27.0.0
>   cordova-android-support-gradle-release : WROTE 
>   /Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/Projects/ALMAMobile2018new/platforms/android/build.gradle
>
> > 27.0.0 ANDROID_HOME=/Users/patrick/Library/Android/sdk JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home studio Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app
> >     publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All
> >     variants are now published.
> >     +----------------------------------------------------------------- | cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 26.+
> >     +----------------------------------------------------------------- Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
> >     'implementation' instead. The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been
> >     deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
> >     Task.doLast(Action) instead.  at
> >     build_3hryrh0pg6ab0no59n7gqttl4.run(/Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/Projects/ALMAMobile2018new/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:149)
> >     Could not find google-services.json while looking in
> >     [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug,
> >     src/nullnullDebug] registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
> >     registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
> >     google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release,
> >     src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
> >     registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
> >     registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection) :CordovaLib:preBuild
> >     UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> >     :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
> >     UP-TO-DATE :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
> >     NO-SOURCE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> >     UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues
> >     :app:generateDebugResources :app:processDebugGoogleServices Parsing
> >     json file:
> >     /Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/Projects/ALMAMobile2018new/platforms/android/app/google-services.json
> >     :app:mergeDebugResources :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> >     UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
> >     :app:generateDebugSources :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk
> >     NO-SOURCE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders
> >     UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:extractTryWithResourcesSupportJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
> >     :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug
> >     UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> >     :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     :app:validateSigningDebug :app:packageDebug :app:assembleDebug
> >     :app:cdvBuildDebug

and here the code I use in javascript (working in ios) which I call AFTER document ready.

> try {
>               this.push = PushNotification.init({
>                   "android": {
>                       sound:true
>                   },
>                   "ios": {
>                       "sound": "true",
>                       "alert": "true",
>                       "badge": "true",
>                       "clearBadge": "true",
>                       categories: {
>                           invite: {
>                               yes: {
>                                   callback: 'accept',
>                                   title: 'Accept',
>                                   foreground: true,
>                                   destructive: false
>                               },
>                               no: {
>                                   callback: 'reject',
>                                   title: 'Reject',
>                                   foreground: false,
>                                   destructive: false
>                               },
>                               maybe: {
>                                   callback: 'maybe',
>                                   title: 'Maybe',
>                                   foreground: true,
>                                   destructive: true
>                               }
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }
>               }); } catch(e){ //will fo to exception mentioning it does not know PushNotification }

and here the list of plugins installed

> code-push 2.0.6 "CodePushAcquisition"
>   com.telerik.cordovaPlatformSpecificFiles 0.1.0 "Cordova Platform
>   Specific Files" cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.2.0
>   "cordova-android-support-gradle-release" cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1
>   "Camera" cordova-plugin-code-push 1.11.12 "CodePush"
>   cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat" cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4
>   "Device" cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.3 "Device Motion"
>   cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.5 "Device Orientation"
>   cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.1 "Notification" cordova-plugin-file 4.3.1
>   "File" cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.1 "File Transfer"
>   cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.1 "Geolocation"
>   cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.5 "Globalization"
>   cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
>   cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
>   cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.6
>   "CDVBackgroundGeolocation" cordova-plugin-media 2.4.1 "Media"
>   cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.1 "Capture"
>   cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.1 "Network Information"
>   cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.1 "Splashscreen"
>   cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2-dev "StatusBar"
>   cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.3 "Vibration" cordova-plugin-whitelist
>   1.3.1 "Whitelist" cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast" cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
>   cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0
>   "cordova-support-google-services" phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.0
>   "BarcodeScanner" phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
>   phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"

Comment: Which cordova version are you at? I had something similar where the push notification plugin was skipped because the used android version 7.1.0 was not supported by the current plugin 2.2.3 . In the config.xml I resorted to using <engine name="android" spec="~7.0.0" />

Comment: You where right there was a mix in the versions and the plugin was not added thanks